# Merge two xts objects (matrices) into a single array in R

Tags: arrays, r, merge, xts

I have two xts objects.

```
> require(quantmod)

> getSymbols("GLD;SLV")
[1] "GLD" "SLV"

> head(SLV, n=2)
           SLV.Open SLV.High SLV.Low SLV.Close SLV.Volume SLV.Adjusted
2007-01-03   129.96   131.16  124.70    125.58    7480000        12.56
2007-01-04   126.04   127.97  125.45    125.80    3220000        12.58

> head(GLD, n=2)
           GLD.Open GLD.High GLD.Low GLD.Close GLD.Volume GLD.Adjusted
2007-01-03    63.58    64.02   62.00     62.28    8061900        62.28
2007-01-04    62.07    62.50   61.52     61.65    4858600        61.65

> NROW(SLV) == NROW(GLD)
[1] TRUE
```

How can you 'stack' these separate two-dimensional matrices into a single three-dimensional array?

Something along the lines of the following:

```
metal <- xts_stacking_function (GLD, SLV)

class(metal)
[1] "array"

metal[1,,1]
              GLD.Open GLD.High GLD.Low GLD.Close GLD.Volume GLD.Adjusted
2007-01-03    63.58    64.02      62     62.28    8061900        62.28
```

Comment: First, GLD and SLV are not arrays, they are xts objects.  Second, what do you mean here by a 3D array?   If you want them to share the index, try newvar<-merge(SLV, GLD).

Comment: Can you provide an example of the output you want?

Comment: @bill merge(SLV, GLD) will return an xts object of two dimensions, not the array object I'm looking for.

Comment: @Milktrader: Does it have to be an array?  Would a list of xts objects work?  If you describe a bit more of what you're trying to do, maybe we can create a solution.

Comment: @Joshua, I considered using a list of xts objects versus an array and thought maybe the array would be simpler, but I'm reconsidering that approach. My end goal is to organize a large group of permutations of a trade system, each with their associated trade signal and return, and then easily make calculations on the entire 'space'. I'll give it some more thought and perhaps pose a better question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think xts objects support 3d arrays. You'll probably need an ugly solution like the one below. Putting everything into an array coerces things to numeric values. But at least this preserves the date index, albeit in a different format because arrays can only have one data type.

```
require(quantmod)
getSymbols("GLD;SLV")
GLD <- cbind(index(GLD), as.matrix(GLD))
SLV <- cbind(index(SLV), as.matrix(SLV))
C <- array(,c(dim(GLD),2))
C[,,1] <- GLD
C[,,2] <- SLV
```

Comment: it appears to be dropping the date, which is important for my purposes. I'll add more code above so you can duplicate it, if you like.

Comment: See my edit. I'm afraid there won't be a really clean solution here. Hopefully someone else can chyme in with something nicer.

Comment: I'm afraid you may be correct, and there is no way to create an array from xts objects. I was hoping that arrays would be able to grant a waiver to the one-data-type rule to xts and zoo objects, because that's exactly what matrices have done. Essentially, an xts object is a matrix, indexed to time, no?

Comment: @Milktrader: yes xts/zoo objects are just a matrix with an "index" attribute.

Answer (score 1):

Given your latest comment, I think you could do what you want in one of two ways:

1. use `lapply` with a list of xts objects
2. use `eapply` with xts objects stored in their own environment

An example of #2 using getSymbols (note that `eapply` returns a list):

```
library(quantmod)
myEnv <- new.env()
getSymbols("GLD;SLV", env=myEnv)
eapply(myEnv, function(x) head(Cl(x),3))
# $SLV
#            SLV.Close
# 2007-01-03    125.58
# 2007-01-04    125.80
# 2007-01-05    121.80
# 
# $GLD
#            GLD.Close
# 2007-01-03     62.28
# 2007-01-04     61.65
# 2007-01-05     60.17
```